# Receive push notification in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

I am developing `Windows 8.1 Application` and want to implement push notification using `WNS`.

I have updated my app to dashboard and also associated my app with app store . I followed `Push` and periodic notifications client-side sample.

I debugged this sample and found the channel `URI` (notify.....com) .I am trying to get my app channel Uri but I am not able to get any Uri .I think I am not implemented properly.

Please help me to troubleshoot this issue and share some idea for the below points.

1. How to associate `Windows 8.1 App` with `App Store`.
2. How to enable `Push Notification Service` using `WNS` ( any other procedure also).
3. Local Configuration.
4. How to get channel `URI`.

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUEC1.png)

---

Please find the error on the below attached image.

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to associate Windows 8.1 App with App Store.** 
In your store dashboard navigate to the particular app and on the left you will see a list having items like analyitcs,services etc. Click on services->Push Notification. Then click on the live service site. See Screenshot[image]

Then update your solution with Name and publisher. This should set you up. and also take cares of question 2 and 3 of your post.(Associating your app from store should do this automatically once you have enabled push from dashboard)

And to get channel URI just call the following method in your code:

```
PushNotificationChannel channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

var myuri = channel.Uri;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have compared everything as you described . Everything is correct  in first question. In third question , I have tried the same code but I could not able to get any URI. I have checked my app Mani-feast file with app identity . Every thing  looks correct. But I can not find any URI.

Comment: Update the answer. All you need to do is channel.Uri to get the uri.

Comment: I get an error from this code as shown in the image [enter image description here][1]** .Please help me to troubleshoot.

Comment: I guess you are trying this on simulator. If yes then that is the expected behaviour. Can you try it on local machine. See the link for more details(https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/294eb60a-a4c7-4a49-9d2b-f019af17c613/the-notification-platform-does-not-have-the-proper-privileges-to-complete-the-request?forum=winappswithcsharp)

Comment: Yes, I was trying in Simulator . I am implementing this app for Tablet . Whether It will work.

Comment: It will work fine. Its just that Simulator doesn't support push. And if it works for you then you can mark it as answer :)

Comment: Thanks Code Noob , but I get below error in local machine.   An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: A notification channel request for the provided application identifier is in progress. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x803E0103).   And finally App stopped debugging.

Comment: Thank you . I got the Channel URI.

Comment: Great..Happy coding. And if this answer helped you then you can mark this as answer

Comment: Hi CodeNoob, I am facing another problem  on push notification. It is showing time out error more than 15 days. And I am not able to receive push notification. Please help me to troubleshoot this . and also share me some code for local configuration to receive push notification. Please help me .

Comment: Hey, The channel URI expires after 15 or 30 days and you need to renew the channel URI. and not sure what do u meant by local configuration. Do you mean local push notification?

Comment: Hi CodeNoob,
I have used the below code to receive push notification.But I am not able to get any push notification. Please check out the below code .Please help me.

channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync(); if (channel !=null) { string uri = channel.Uri.ToString(); channel.PushNotificationReceived += channel_PushNotificationReceived;
}